# iPhone's NSUserdefaults is a database or plist

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, nsuserdefaults

I am not able to get NSUserDefaults concepts properly. Is that a database of plist file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a key-value store that is persisted between restarts of your application. How it's implemented has little bearing on how you use it.

Comment: What is the default way of storage ? db or file ?

Comment: thndrkiss, it doesn't matter, all you need to know is that it persists your data between app runs. Read what Stephen Darlington wrote!

Comment: Why does it matter? It's not documented so you shouldn't make any assumptions about how it is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's different on the iPhone OS (which i don't believe) but in Mac OS X is it a plist file in your Library/Preferences folder. Pretty sure it's the same on iPhone OS/iOS