# Iphone App Registration User Data Log

Tags: iphone, objective-c

At the start of my application i make my users to register first then take them to login View.I want to save the successfully registered users and let them get to the loginView instead of Register View.

How can i do this.As far i know iphone is registered as one user.Tell me what is the best way.And how to keep the user data and redirect to login view for a user?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use NSUserDefaults to save user data such as login info.

Take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/10/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-savingretrieving-data-using-nsuserdefaults/) and the [reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

In Short, you would do something like:

Saving after registration:

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[prefs setObject:@"UserName" forKey:@"UserName"];
[prefs setObject:@"Pass" forKey:@"Pass"];
// This is suggested to synch prefs, but is not needed
[prefs synchronize];
```

Retrieving on app start:

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *userName = [prefs stringForKey:@"UserName"];
NSString *pass = [prefs stringForKey:@"Pass"];
```

Comment: ok..i am making a try with this approach...will let you know what happens..thanks for reply..

Comment: Can you explain what the SetObject:@"UserName" doing here?I need to register a user with any name and save it on preference/log.And when opening app let him redirect to login page checking if this user is already register.I am little confused with my approch.Can you suggest me the best way?

Comment: With this approach, you save the username and password of a registered user in NSUSerDefaults. And retrieve it at app start, or whenever you want to check if the user login info has been saved to user defaults.

Comment: [prefs setObject:@"Max" forKey:@"UserName"]; would save the username Max with key UserName in the NSUSerDefaults. At the next start you can do something like `if([prefs stringForKey:@"UserName"]!=nil) sendToLoginWithUsername:[prefs stringForKey:@"UserName"]; else sendToRegister;`

Comment: ok..can you tell me where it's saving the user information?can i check it?

Comment: i made a try.But when i am checking if any user is registered it's not getting any user.I am testing on my simulator.I need to know where it saves the user information?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178115/iphones-nsuserdefaults-is-a-database-or-plist It is getting no users because you probably didn't save any yet. Please, also read the reference I posted in the answer.